# Was change in the way tweets are oneboxed intentional? Is the old way or the new way better?

Tags: support, chat, onebox, twitter

Twitter messages are among the types of content that can [get oneboxed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/onebox/info) when posted in chat.

I have noticed that the way twitter posts are oneboxed changed not too long ago. You can see the difference if you choose some random room with enough oneboxed tweets and [search for them in the transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q="ob+tweet"&room=64176). (Just compare how tweets are displayed since October 2017 and before that - AFAICT the change happened around that time.) Still, here are a few I [tested in Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1/2017/10/29) - I have also added link to the way the tweet is displayed in transcript so that the difference between the old and the new way of displaying oneboxed tweets.

The difference is that before the change if the tweet contained also an image, only the text was displayed. Now an image is included in some cases. (I was not able to exactly pinpoint when it is added and when not.)

I did not notice whether this change was announced somewhere. (Of course, I might have missed it?

- Was this change in oneboxing intentional? Is also some content other than tweets?
- If it is not difficult to switch to either of the two possibilities, then perhaps there's some merit to the discussion which of them is better. What do you think?

On one hand, it is nice to see also a picture. But sometimes with pictures the oneboxed tweet might seem too big in chat.

Comment: Must be intentional, because the HTML markup is generated by chat, and has things like `class="ob-tweet-image"`